# Running time analysis of Ford Fulkerson Algorithm that finds the maximum flow in a network

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, ford-fulkerson

I know that the running time of ford fulkerson in general is O(f*(n+m)) where f* is the maximum flow of the network and the n , m are the number of vertices and edges in the network , however what if all edge capacities are bounded by a constant C, how will this affect the running time ?

or will it affect the running time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a simple graph, the given constraint basically means that no more than `c*(n-1)` leave the source. This means `f* <= c*(n-1)`, and since `c` is constant, we can conclude that the running time with no modifications will now be `O(n^2+nm)`.